# Basic AJAX in QWebView

Tags: javascript, c++, ajax, qt, webkit

I've started to learn AJAX which I'll be using inside Qt application, but I'm having a problem with just running a simple example from w3c.

I have a simple window with `QWebView` in the middle which loads index.html (I've also tried hosting the file on local server). Here are the contents of index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="script.js" language="JavaScript"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="myDiv"><h2>Let AJAX change this text</h2></div>
<button type="button" onclick="loadXMLDoc()">Change Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

And script.js:

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  };
xmlhttp.open("GET","text.txt",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

In mainwindow.cpp I also set:

```
QWebSettings::globalSettings()->setAttribute(QWebSettings::JavascriptEnabled, true);
```

The website works fine in a browser, but in QWebView nothing happens after I press the button.

Comment: I have similar problem, and i verify that xmlhttp.status return 0 on my webview. Verify your xmlhttp.status too.